# How to make my method add_friend work in rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm folowwing  Charles Max Wood tutorial on the twitter clone , flitter.
I'm having and error `undefined method friendships` when  I launch rake db:seed .I'am trying to add friend via the rake db:seed task , The method add_friend is define in the User model. But i need help to define  the method friendships  so that the task can work .Thank you a lot for your help .

**Here is the db/seeds.rb file**

```
require 'faker'
require 'populator'

User.destroy_all

10.times do
  user = User.new
  user.username = Faker::Internet.user_name
  user.email = Faker::Internet.email
  user.password = "test"
  user.password_confirmation = "test"
  user.save
end


User.all.each do |user|  
  Flit.populate(5..10) do |flit|
    flit.user_id = user.id
    flit.message = Faker::Lorem.sentence
  end

  3.times do
    User.add_friend(User.all[rand(User.count)])
  end
end
```

**and there is the user file.**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # new columns need to be added here to be writable through mass assignment
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :prepare_password

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email, :allow_blank => true
  validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[-\w\._@]+$/i, :allow_blank => true, :message => "should only contain letters, numbers, or .-_@"
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 4, :allow_blank => true

  has_many :flits, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships



  def self.add_friend(friend)
    friendship = friendships.build(:friend_id => friend.id)
      if !friendship.save
        logger.debug "User '#{friend.email}' already exists in the user's friendship list."
      end
  end

  # login can be either username or email address
  def self.authenticate(login, pass)
    user = find_by_username(login) || find_by_email(login)
    return user if user && user.password_hash == user.encrypt_password(pass)
  end

  def encrypt_password(pass)
    BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(pass, password_salt)
  end

  private

  def prepare_password
    unless password.blank?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = encrypt_password(password)
    end
  end
end
```

**friendship.rb**

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'
  validates_uniqueness_of :friend_id, :scope => :user_id
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :friend_id
end
```

Comment: could u post the full error trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to be doing is calling `add_friend` on the *instance* `user`, and not on the *class* `User`:

```
3.times do
  user.add_friend(User.all[rand(User.count)])
end
```

Also your `add_friend` method should be an instance method, not a class method, so you don't need the `self`:

```
def add_friend(friend)
  friendship = friendships.build(:friend_id => friend.id)
    if !friendship.save
      logger.debug "User '#{friend.email}' already exists in the user's friendship list."
    end
end
```

Comment: You're right ,sorry iHave already done that just make an error while . i was asking the question.but i've modify the add_friend to self.add_friend but the error i'm getting is undefined method friendships ,w wich is inside add_friend

Comment: No what you had originally was correct. It should be `def add_friend` and not `def self.add_friend`. Please read my answer carefully.

Comment: But when i don't define it as a class method i'm getting the error on the add_friend

Comment: Did you update the code in the rake task? It should be `user.add_friend` and not `User.add_friend`. You are adding a friend to the *instance* not to the *class*.

Comment: yeah i just did it and it work .So basicaly the error was the fact that i was calling the user class instead of the simple user thank you alot been on it for over a day now –

Comment: You're welcome. The instance/class thing can be confusing but it's pretty fundamental, make sure you understand what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

You should define this method as a class method not instance method:

```
  def self.add_friend(friend)
    friendship = friendships.build(:friend_id => friend.id)
      if !friendship.save
        logger.debug "User '#{friend.email}' already exists in the user's friendship list."
      end
  end
```

Comment: You're right ,sorry iHave already done that just make an error while . i was asking the question.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `add_friend` references `friendships`, which is defined on the instance and not on the class, so it should be an instance method not a class method. This part of the original code was correct.

Comment: But when i don't define it as a class method i'm getting the error on the add_friend

Comment: yeah i just did it and it work .So basicaly the error was the fact that i was calling the user class instead of the simple user  thank you alot been on it for over a  day now